# Pythonic way - Ternary vs or

Tags: python, logical-operators, conditional-operator

I'm really just wondering, when it comes to this type of situation, what is the pythonic way of doing it? Using an `if else` ternary or an `or`:

```py
true_list = []
for x, y in a_list: # x, y could be any truthy or falsy value
  true_list.append(x or y)
  true_list.append(x if x else y)
```

**Edit:** I updated the question to ignore the semantics, I was mostly wondering about which expression is more pythonic.

Comment: If you write `string += x if x is not None else y` you don't need the comment. It does handle the empty string differently compared to what you have.

Comment: You can't ignore semantics. Code that doesn't do what you intend is *not* Pythonic.

Comment: `x if x or y` isn't even syntactically correct; I assume you mean `x if x else y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the situation for which the conditional operator was *introduced*; use it.

```
string += x if x else y  # Or ... if x is not None ... if the distinction is necessary
```

In general, use `or` when you only care about the truthiness of the expression, without caring about the "actual" value whose truthiness is under consideration.

The conditional expression was introduced because many people tried to write code like

```
<condition> and x or y
```

but this is subtlely wrong: the intention is for the expression to equal `x` if the condition is true, but it really only equals `x` if *both* the condition and `x` are true.

Comment: this is what i would do, more readable and usually common in python.

Comment: I updated the question to better reflect what I meant!

Answer (score 1):

In the case where both `x` and `y` can be `None` you could do the more verbose:

```
>>> string = ""
>>> x, y = (None, None)
>>> string += x if x else y if y else '' # Fallback to empty string
>>> string
''
```